# Grouping members of a collection by category in a Meteor template

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js

I have a single `Workouts` collection, each object having a `category` and a `name`. At the HTML layer, I'm creating a category header, then displaying a list of workouts beneath.

I have it working, but there's no way I'm doing it the meteor and/or handlebars way. Think I'm struggling with understanding the context of `this`, as well as how to pass data into a template.

Here are my template functions:

```
Template.categories.getCategories = ->                                             
  workouts = Workouts.find().fetch()                                               
  categories = _.map workouts, (workout) -> workout.category                       
  _.uniq categories                                                                

Template.workouts.getWorkouts = ->                                                 
  Workouts.find {category: this.toString()},                                       
    sort: ['category', 'name']
```

And here's the template file:

```
<head>                                                                                                                         
</head>                                                                            

<body>                                                                                                                              
  {{> categories}}                                                                 
</body>                                                                            

<template name="categories">                                                       
  {{#each getCategories}}                                                          
    <h2>{{this}}</h2>                                                              
    {{> workouts}}                                                                 
  {{/each}}                                                                        
</template>                                                                        

<template name="workouts">                                                         
  {{#each getWorkouts}}                                                            
    <div class="workout container">                                                
      <div>                                                                        
        {{name}}                                                                   
      </div>                                                                       
      <div>                                                                        
        {{units}}                                                                  
      </div>                                                                       
    </div>                                                                         
  {{/each}}                                                                        
</template>
```

Inside `Template.categories.getCategories`, `this` is `Window`. But inside of `Template.categories.getCategories`, it's the string object equivalent of the `this` inside the `categories` template, which is a string literal. Huh?

Again, this works. I get a category heading with a list of workouts beneath, but what's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your implementation leaves that much to improve though maybe the below is a bit clearer by avoiding `this`.

Sorry I don't know Coffeescript so figured I should avoid confusion by writing javascript.

```
Template.categories.getCategories = function(){  
  var categories = Workouts.find({}, {sort: {category: 1}, fields: {category: 1}}).fetch();

  return _.uniq( categories, true, function (workout){ 
    return workout.category;
  });    
};                                            

Template.categories.workouts = function ( category ){
  return Workouts.find( { category: category}, { sort: {name : 1}});
};

<template name="categories">                                                       
  {{#each getCategories}}                                                          
    <h2>{{category}}</h2>                                                              
    {{#each workouts category}}
      {{> workout}}                                                                 
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}                                                                        
</template>                                                                        

<template name="workout">                                                                                                               
  <div class="workout container">                                                
    <div>                                                                        
      {{name}}                                                                   
    </div>                                                                       
    <div>                                                                        
      {{units}}                                                                  
    </div>                                                                       
  </div>                                                                                                                                            
</template>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. In the `categories` template, your `category` is undefined because `getCategory` returns an array of strings, not an object. I think this is where the confusion stems from. Instead of `getCategories` returning an array of strings, maybe the better approach is to query the collection for distinct categories and return a collection of `Workouts` that's a subset of all `Workouts`. Not only does that shift work from JS to the DB, but it also makes what's happening in the template a bit more clear.

Comment: Other question: Are you sure you can pass args into a template like this? Inside of `Template.categories.workouts`, `category` is always undefined.

Comment: The problem is just in using _.uniq then.  I will update code.

Comment: I needed to fetch the cursor for _.uniq.  Works now.  If you need the categories anywhere else it is probably best just to hold them in a local collection.