# Iterating over nested each statements in meteorjs (group by category)

Tags: javascript, meteor, each

I have a list of products, each of which has a category associated with it.
I am trying to list out the products grouped by category similar to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896769/grouping-members-of-a-collection-by-category-in-a-meteor-template) but I cannot get it it to work. It just shows up a unique list of the categories but not the products

I have the following helper:

```
Template.supplierPage.helpers({
getCategories: function(){
     var categories = Products.find({supplierId: this._id}, 
                    {sort:{category: 1}, fields: {category: 1}}).fetch();
     return _.uniq( categories, true, function (product){ 
        return product.category;
    });    
},
  products: function(category) {
     return Products.find({category: category, supplierId: this._id});
  }
});
```

And the following template:

```
<template name="supplierPage">
<div class="ui dividing header">
    <h3 class="ui header">My Products</h3>
</div>
<div>
    {{> productCreate}}

    {{#each getCategories}} 
        <h1>{{category}}</h1>
            {{#each products.category}}
                {{> productItem}}
            {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right. You are just not providing the argument to the `products` helper in the right way. This should work:

```
<template name="supplierPage">
<div class="ui dividing header">
    <h3 class="ui header">My Products</h3>
</div>
<div>
    {{> productCreate}}

    {{#each getCategories}} 
        <h1>{{category}}</h1>
            {{#each products category ../_id}}
                {{> productItem}}
            {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

You also need to fix your use of `this` in the `products` helper, because it changes when using `#each`. The easiest is to provide it as an additional argument as above:

```
products: function(category, supplier) {
   return Products.find({category: category, supplierId: supplier});
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! You have just made my day!